# RollingCurl выполняет запросы не по очереди

Tags: php, curl

Сделаю запрос через RollingCurl а класс почему то выполняет запросы разные, а надо именно что бы шел по очереди как этого сделать может кто то знает? [вот запросы](http://naimjo3s.bget.ru/example.php)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так ->
https://github.com/chuyskywalker/rolling-curl

```
$rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
$rollingCurl
->get('http://yahoo.com')
->get('http://google.com')
->get('http://hotmail.com')
->get('http://msn.com')
->get('http://reddit.com')
->setCallback(function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) {
    // parsing html with regex is evil (http://bit.ly/3x9sQX), but this is just a demo
    if (preg_match("#<title>(.*)</title>#i", $request->getResponseText(), $out)) {
        $title = $out[1];
    }
    else {
        $title = '[No Title Tag Found]';
    }
    echo "Fetch complete for (" . $request->getUrl() . ") $title " . PHP_EOL;
})
->setSimultaneousLimit(3)
->execute();
```